# "after finishing her trip, latest by March 2015, she will..."

Tags: meaning, word-order

The sentence is

> after finishing her trip, latest by March 2015, she will continue to work for us.

What does that mean?
What is March 2015 related to? To the end of her trip or to the end of her work?

Comment: It's bad writing/"journalese". The writer should have used ***at the** latest by March 2015*, or more elegantly, *by March 2015 **at the latest***. The precise date when she will finish her trip is unknown, but it definitely won't be any later than sometime in March 2015 (of course, it might be *much* earlier).

Comment: It could also just have been written by a non-native speaker. _Latest_ is a direct translation of phrases that mean ‘at the latest’ or ‘no later than’ in several other languages I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

It's the usual stilted language you find PR lackeys using. It means that she is expected to finish her trip by March 2015 (at the latest), and will then resume work.

Answer (score 0):

i think it means at the latest, that is, she will finish her trip by March 15 or earlier (but won't be late that that)